# React native: How to return in original url after the response is success?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this current url when changing password http://localhost:8080/html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnbWFpbC5jb218N3F0eHJn, How can i remove the **html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnbWFpbC5jb218N3F0eHJn** when the response success?

```
if(response.status==200){
    MySwal.fire(
       'Successful!',
       'Your Password Changed successfully',
       'success'
    )
    navigation.replace('Login')
}else{
    MySwal.fire(
       'Error!',
       'Link doesnt exists.',
       'error'
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using this

```
window.location.assign(window.location.origin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the `location` object in JavaScript?

```
const urlPath = location.pathname; /* /a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnbWFpbC5jb218N3F0eHJn */
const urlOrigin = location.origin; /* http://localhost:8080 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this somewhere in your utils

```
const extractPath = () => {
  let url = "http://localhost:8080/html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnbWFpbC5jb218N3F0eHJn"
  let path = url.split('?');
  return path[0];
  // returns [
  //     'http://localhost:8080/html', 
  //     'a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnbWFpbC5jb218N3F0eHJn'
  // ]
};
```

You can extract the url as a parameter to make it reusable.

Comment: this html?a2V2aW50cmluaWRhZDUxMkBnbWFpbC5jb218N3F0eHJn" still exist